# Prevent authentication from specific machines

Tags: windows, group-policy

I have two domains PRIMARY and DEV. These both contain matching service accounts for various applications. PRIMARY also contains user accounts  We have a one way trust relationship such that DEV trusts PRIMARY so that users do not need matching accounts to log into DEV machines. However, we want to prevent DEV service accounts from trying to hit resources in PRIMARY (and because password is different, it causes the service account in PRIMARY to become locked).

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Are you saying you have an existing issue of PRIMARY service accounts being locked out by the equivalent in the DEV domain or that you want to take proactive measures to prevent this from happening? As Ryan Ries has said, if you have a one way trust (DEV trusting Primary) then you should not have an issue with PRIMARY service accounts being locked out.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I follow... that is the definition of a one-way trust. Users in the trusted domain can access resources in the trusting domain, but not the other way around.

Now if you wanted to block users in one domain from even *attempting* authentication... like not even having network connectivity, then... firewalls.

Comment: Firewall or Windows IPSec restrictions (same-same).